# Please help ... Cannot compile "Point Cloud Library"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, netbeans, cmake, point-cloud-library

I'm new to C++ and want to compile PCL example
I installed VS 2010 and Netbeans 7 but could not compile it ! Is the re a better IDE for cMake ?

The code has CMakeLists.txt file.

What should I do ?

These are source files :
https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/apps/cloud_composer

Comment: If it has a cmakelist.txt file then the simple thing would be to use cmake to generate a VS 2010 project for you and then use VS 2010 as your IDE.

Comment: And it's better if you post the error you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to:

- C++, and
- PCL, and
- VS2010, and
- CMake

Then I would advice you to start with the prebuild binaries from PCL. You can find them
from: [Prebuild windows PCL binaries](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html) . Probably best to select the 32-bit anyhow, even if you have a 64-bits windows. If 64-bits is needed later, you can install that prebuild binary.

After installation of the binary and pdb-files, you can start a new project and copy an example from the PCL tutorials. In order to make it build, you need to set up VS2010 correctly.
This is explained at: [VS2010 configuration for PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514762/point-cloud-library-on-visual-studio?rq=1)